# Handling a NullPointerException, assuming that is the issue

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, arduino

I am getting a "Force Close" which I am guessing is from an unhandled exception. My code below sends an HTTP request from my Android phone to an Arduino acting as a webserver. If the Arduino doesn't respond, for instance if it isn't connected, I would like to gracefully notify the user of this rather than just have the application stop unexpectedly and show the "Force Close" dialogue.

In the code below, I have placed a comment where I think the exception may be occurring. Is that likely the issue and if so how I should fix it? If not, what else in my code is messed up?

I have included the error messages from [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) at the bottom.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
    int timeoutSocket = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    //Send command to turn on outlet 1 "?aaa/"
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://24.44.23.65:150/?aaa/");
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Convert response to a string

    //*********************************************************************************
    // I think the problem might be happening at the next line because if the try/catch
    // block above results in an exception, "response" will still be null and there
    // won't be an HttpEntity to get.
    //*********************************************************************************

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    try{
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String state = sb.toString().trim();

    //Test response and update button
    if(state.contains("Done")){
        //not sure how all of this works but it does
        v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFFFF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        Drawable d = outletOneOFF.getBackground();
        outletOneOFF.invalidateDrawable(d);
        d.clearColorFilter();
        ((Button) v).setText("Light is On");
        outletOneOFF.setText("OFF");
    }
    else
        if(state.contains("Error"))
        {
            ((Button) v).setText("ERROR");
        }
}
```

Error log:

```
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at com.banatwala.aquarium.outlets$1.onClick(outlets.java:70)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9291)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4419)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:846)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
09-19 17:13:37.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22814):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 17:13:37.806: D/dalvikvm(22814): GC_CONCURRENT freed 343K, 49% free 2903K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 7ms+3ms
```

Comment: What's line 70 in the `onClick`'s file?

Comment: If execute() resulted in an exception, you should see the stack trace in the log.

Comment: Why are you using HttpPost if you aren't posting any data with the request? You never call `setEntity()` on your HttpPost object

Comment: Oh....I had no idea that those numbers corresponded to line numbers.....or even how to view the line numbers in eclipse.  Now that that is solved this may be much easier.  I am getting warnings where expected that show system.errors at the execute().  I placed the line `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();` within the `try` and caught the NullPointerException.  But I guess now the issue is that if the execute() doesn't work then everything after that is useless as well.  Is there an acceptable way to break out of the button click event handler at that point?

Comment: @DavidWasser - I am using HttpPost because that just happened to be the first thing that I came across in a google search for sending a request to a server.  The data is actually the `?aaa/` because I have the arduino discarding each character in the request until is reaches a "?" and then it takes every letter after that in sequence to determine what action it needs to take so in this case the first 'a' in `?aaa/` translates as manual control, the second 'a' translates as "Pin 10", and the third 'a' translates as "On".  `?acb/` would translate as "manual" -> "Pin 12" -> "Off".

Comment: Another problem down the road for you. I'm not sure at what level it starts, but in Ice Cream Sandwich you have to do http stuff in a background thread. I'm doing ICS for the first time and blew up because I didn't use AsyncTask. It devolved to a null pointer problem as well.

Comment: if you get an error doing the HTTP stuff you can just put up a toast and "return". That will get you out of the button click event handler. As @HowardHodson says, you should do the HTTP stuff in a separate thread anyway.

Comment: Try using HttpGet instead of HttpPost and see if that helps. But you should be able to catch whatever exceptions are going on and troubleshoot those.

Comment: @HowardHodson - haven't learned "threads" yet.  I guess no time like the present :-)

Comment: @DavidWasser - thank you very much for the suggestions!  I have a working eventHandler now by just catching all of the errors but it is not very pretty or elegant looking.  I'm going to clean it up using your suggestions and then re-post my entire code for review.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your result is not null and notify the User if it fails:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
    int timeoutSocket = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    //Send command to turn on outlet 1 "?aaa/"
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://24.44.23.65:150/?aaa/");
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Convert response to a string

    // Try this:

    if(response != null) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        try{
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String state = sb.toString().trim();

        //Test response and update button
        if(state.contains("Done")){
            //not sure how all of this works but it does
            v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFFFF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            Drawable d = outletOneOFF.getBackground();
            outletOneOFF.invalidateDrawable(d);
            d.clearColorFilter();
            ((Button) v).setText("Light is On");
            outletOneOFF.setText("OFF");
        }
        else
            if(state.contains("Error"))
            {
                ((Button) v).setText("ERROR");
            }
    } else {
        // ******************************
        // notify the User that the Arduino is not available
        // like
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot connect to the Arduino!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // ******************************
    }
}
```